# Python Tkinter renders slower after every restart of the program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that uses the multiprocessing library to start a client (that uses Tkinter) and a server with which they communicate through Asyncio's networking library. When the client closes, it sends a packet to the server that tells it to shut itself down as well. In the main program that runs these processes, I use a multiprocessing Pipe to allow the client to tell the main program when it closes. After it receives a message over this Pipe, it calls .kill() on both the client and the server processes, and then joins them (which is probably redundant).

After restarting my machine, the program runs and renders fine. However, after running this program multiple times, the client renders visibly slower. Every time I re-run it, the individual widgets take progressively longer to fully render. The only way to make it render quickly again is to restart my entire computer. I am running this with VS Code.

What could even be causing this? I have to assume it's a memory leak of some kind, but I assumed that Python's GIL and automatic garbage collection would make this impossible as long as I was sure that every process was terminated at the end of running.

EDIT:

I am using Pyinstaller to compile this code, so I decided to test something. I noticed that this slowdown in rendering remains and compounds even when running the *compiled version of the code*. This version has Python built in to the file. So this slow down is consistently occurring even across different instances of Python.

To clarify, here is a toy example that explains what is happening:

- Run script -> 0.1 seconds to render
- Run script -> 0.2 seconds to render
- Run executable -> 0.3 seconds to render
- Run script -> 0.4 seconds to render
- Run executable -> 0.5 seconds to render

EDIT 2:

I've tested this on multiple different machines (and multiple different OSes) and have been unable to replicate the problem. I think this isn't a problem with Python or Tkinter, but possibly a bug related to my system specifically. Oh well!

Comment: When you restart the process, python's GIL as well as the whole python process is shutdown, deleted from memory and then a new python process starts with its own GIL. I don't think it's because of the GIL.

Comment: Try timing your code using `python -m cProfile -o output.file {script_name}` and then run `import pstats; pstats.Stats("output.file").sort_stats("cumtime").print_stats(number)`. That will tell you the slowest function run. Use that to narrow the problem down to a few functions that you can manually optimise.

Comment: I'm not sure if you responded before or after I made my edit, but I updated it to clarify that I don't think this has to do with my code directly. I believe that running the code is changing something in my system that causes subsequent runs to render slower.

Comment: Does your program interact with any external files/processes/window's registry/... (except the `os.pipe`)? Also there is no way that I can tell you the problem without seeing the code. I haven't seen this issue anywhere else. Also have you tried running the python script multiple times from IDLE. I might be a bug in VSCode or python (very unlikely). Do you have a GitHub repository with your code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the entire codebase, and I'm not even really sure what parts of it I could share to replicate the issue. I believe the bug is entirely within my system. Even when compiled to an executable, it still occurs so it's not a bug with IDLE/VS Code. Very strange issue. Since it's only my machine, I'm not too worried about solving it. I appreciate your help!